# Construct a matrix with lines information

Tags: r, matrix, lines, reshape

I would like to solve this problem:

I wanna to convert that format:

```
Samples Genotype  Region 
sample1    A      Region1
sample1    B      Region2
sample1    A      Region3
sample2    A      Region2
sample2    B      Region3
sample3    B      Region1
sample3    A      Region3
```

To a genotype matrix, including a tag to missing genotypes:

```
Samples   Region1 Region2 Region3
sample1     A       B      A
sample2     X       A      B
sample3     B       X      A
```

It is possible to do in R software?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Samples Genotype  Region 
sample1    A      Region1
sample1    B      Region2
sample1    A      Region3
sample2    A      Region2
sample2    B      Region3
sample3    B      Region1
sample3    A      Region3", header = TRUE)
```

You can use the `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
dat2 <- dcast(dat, Samples ~ Region, value.var = "Genotype")
```

In the result, missing values are indicated by `NA`:

```
#   Samples Region1 Region2 Region3
# 1 sample1       A       B       A
# 2 sample2    <NA>       A       B
# 3 sample3       B    <NA>       A
```

`NA`s are appropriate to represent missing data. But you can replace the `NA`s by `X`s with the following command:

```
dat2[is.na(dat2)] <- "X"

#   Samples Region1 Region2 Region3
# 1 sample1       A       B       A
# 2 sample2       X       A       B
# 3 sample3       B       X       A
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the "base R" `reshape` equivalent of Sven's answer (+1, Sven):

```
reshape(dat, direction = "wide", idvar = "Samples", timevar="Region")
#   Samples Genotype.Region1 Genotype.Region2 Genotype.Region3
# 1 sample1                A                B                A
# 4 sample2             <NA>                A                B
# 6 sample3                B             <NA>                A
```

Replace the `NA` in the same manner if necessary.